# C# - SQLite Insufficient parameters supplied to the command error

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, parameters

This is so simple, yet I can not see where the mistake is! The parameter is not added in the query. Here is my code:

```
SQLiteDB db;
db = new SQLiteDB(Config.getMasterUsersDB());
DataTable masterUsers;
SQLiteCommand query = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT username , password , localDB FROM master_users WHERE username = @username");
query.Parameters.Add("@username", comboMasterUsers.SelectedItem.ToString());
masterUsers = db.GetDataTable(query.CommandText);

foreach (DataRow r in masterUsers.Rows)
{
     if (txtPassword.Text == r["password"].ToString())
     {
          Config.setLocalDB(r["localDB"].ToString());
          Config.setLoggedMasterUser(r["username"].ToString());

          this.Hide();
          formMain formMain = new formMain();
          formMain.Show();
     }
}
```

SQLiteDB is a helper class to make the database connection and retrievals

```
public DataTable GetDataTable(string sql)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection);
            cnn.Open();
            SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(cnn);
            mycommand.CommandText = sql;
            SQLiteDataReader reader = mycommand.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(reader);
            reader.Close();
            cnn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Why do i get the Insufficient parameters supplied to the command error? I can not see any typos either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the parameter to the first command object (`query`), but then create a *second* object (`mycommand`) without any parameters.

You have to change `GetDataTable` to add the parameters to its own object:

```
    ...
    string sql = "SELECT ... WHERE username = ?";
    db.GetDataTable(sql, comboMasterUsers.SelectedItem.ToString());
    ...

public DataTable GetDataTable(string sql, params Object[] parameters)
{
    ...
    mycommand.CommandText = sql;
    foreach (var value in parameters)
    {
        var param = mycommand.CreateParameter();
        param.Value = value;
        mycommand.Parameters.Add(param);
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you, great answer. So the parameters are not added to the commandText? I thought it was done like this, so I then sent the commandText to the GetDataTable.

Comment: Parameters bypass any parsing and are passed to the database separately (otherwise, blobs would not work).